# how to access a django webapp REST API endpoint from unix without requiring the user to enter credentials

Tags: django, unix, django-rest-framework, credentials

i have a django webapp running at work.  we have some REST APIs available which get accessed by our flow in unix.  currently to avoid asking the users to enter their credentials, we store a service account name and credentials in a "secret" location on disk.  my python code reads credentials from there to login and access the REST API running on our django app.

i am sure there is a better way to do this.  is there a way to leverage that the user is logged into unix somehow to get authentication to work with the REST API?  i heard kerberos might be useful here?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Doesn't removing the authentication work in your case?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu i need to keep the authentication because certain actions and data available via REST are privileged.

Comment: You can omit authentication to certain views though

Comment: in some cases yes, but in others i cannot omit authentication, hence the question on how to do this properly.

Comment: There are two ways to set up Kerberos : Windows + Active Directory, or else give up your soul to a demon first so that you are immune to pain. Besides, you need a kerberos ticket before the web client can authenticate "auto-magically" via SPNego; and getting the ticket usually means user/password _(there are ways to get the password from a file but that's meant for service accounts...)_

Comment: Didi you consider X509 client cerificates? _(improperly called "SSL client certs" since they are used for mutual auth, not for the SSL/TLS encryption)_

Comment: Oh, I forgot, if your Linux auth is bound to a Kerberos KDC (Active Directory, IPA etc) with SSSD (or a commercial alternative like Centrify) then you _can_ get a Kerberos ticket automatically at login time. It's even renewed automatically. But that's a big "if".